# bash and curl commands gets errors : bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory and curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8192)

Tags: bash, pipe, curl

I am trying to install Litespeed in my Debian instance under Google cloud.
I try :

```
sudo bash <( curl https://get.litespeed.sh ) my_serial_number
```

I get :

```
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8192)
```

Comment: Litespeed is commercial. Why not asking them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *really* wish projects would stop doing this.  Running shell scripts fetched off of some web site is a security risk.  Doing it as root is reckless at best.

Your command does not work as the file or pipe that the process substitution results in is local to the current shell, and you're expecting to read it in a shell started by `sudo`.

I would advice you to download the script separately, then *read it* to figure out exactly what it's doing, what files it's installing and/or changing on your system, and if it *really* needs to be run by root.  Then run the script (now locally downloaded) once you know it is safe to do so.